# Set default Firebase Docs Language

Tags: firebase

Whenever I access the Firebase documentation in Brazil, the docs appear in Portuguese. I found out I can force the English language by appending the `hl=en` parameter to the URL, but I'd like to know if there's a way to make it a default setting.

BTW, I have my Google account set to English already.

Comment: Configure your browser's default language.  The site itself doesn't have its own setting.

Comment: Yeah, in Firefox it works after I set English at the top of preferred languages of webpages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set Language to English. Follow Steps:

1. Go to [Docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/)
2. You will see dropdown menu like image below:

[image: Documantion]

3. Click on it then you will see "English" Click on it. And you will see the page has been converted to English Language.

I hope that I helped you :)